# Python: How to access row/column data outside buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a gameboard application in tkinter. I have 5 rows (1-5) and 6 columns (0-6) of buttons on a canvas. Is there a way to make the row and column integer values of the pressed button accessible inside assign_Func, which is called when button is pressed? I want to assign gameboard[row][column] to the index of the button that was pressed.

My current code produces this error:
line 31, in assign_Func
    gameboard[row][column] = 11
NameError: global name 'row' is not defined

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from Tkinter import Button

gameboard = ([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]])
i = 0

#Essential code              
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, background="blue")
frame.pack(expand = TRUE)
window = Tk()


#Supposed to assign the row and column of the pressed button to the row and column of gameboard.

def assign_Func():
    global gameboard
    global i
    while i < 5:
        gameboard[row][column] = 11
        i = i + 1

#Create buttons in rows 1-5, columns 0-6
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

#column 1
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# column 2
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# column 3
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

# column 4
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

# column 5
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

#column 6
watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=2, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=3, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=4, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

watermark = Button(frame, background = "red", text="~", fg="black", command=assign_Func)
watermark.grid(row=5, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: row & colum aren't defined in your function...

Comment: in `Button` you can assign function with arguments using `lambda` - `comman=lambda:assign_Func(1, 1)`

Comment: BTW: you could use `for` loops to generate all buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to assign function with arguments in `command=`

```
Button(..., command=lambda:assign_Func(1, 1) )
```

and `assign_Func` have to get it

```
def assign_Func(row, column):
```

---

If you will use `for` loop to create `Buttons` then you have to assign value to argument in `lambda`

```
command=lambda r=row,c=col:assign_Func(r, c)
```

In `for` loops

```
for row in range(1, 6):
    for col in range(0, 7):
        b = Button( ... , command=lambda r=row, c=col:assign_Func(r, c))
        b.grid(row=row, column=col, ...)
```

Comment: Great suggestions! I have one more question- I am working on OS X and cannot seem to change the button color. I am using `background = "red", text="~", bg="green", fg="blue"` but the buttons don't change color. Any ideas?

Comment: It uses native widgets - maybe native widgets on OSX doesn't allow to change color. On Linux it changes button colors.